# What is the best way to maintain alignment of a set of equations while putting texts in between?

Tags: math-mode, equations, vertical-alignment, align, text

Sometimes I am writing an aligned list of equations, but I need to break them in the middle to add a comment, like:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}       

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{align*}
    W(z) = A^TAB + \sum\limits_{\omega \in \sigma} a^2 V(z)\int_0^T rm(\theta)d\theta
\end{align*}
Obviously $A^TAB \leq 0$, therefore
\begin{align*}
    W(z) \leq \sum\limits_{\omega \in \sigma} a^2 V(z)\int_0^T rm(\theta)d\theta
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

But it would be better for the equations to remain aligned

[image]

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use an `align` environment, with `\intertext{..}` or `\shortintertext{..}` inside that environment. With `mathtools` get the `\shortintertext` (`\intertext` is there with `amsmath`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\intertext` command to typeset the text. Then you can reduce your example to one environment and align it to your desire:

```
\begin{align*}
    W(z) &= A^TAB + \sum\limits_{\omega \in \sigma} a^2 V(z)\int_0^T rm(\theta)d\theta
\intertext{Obviously $A^TAB \leq 0$, therefore}
    W(z) &\leq \sum\limits_{\omega \in \sigma} a^2 V(z)\int_0^T rm(\theta)d\theta
\end{align*}
```

With the result:

[image: align with \intertext]

---

As [Manuel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357735/what-is-the-best-way-to-maintain-alignment-of-a-set-of-equations-while-putting-t#comment881104_357735) and [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357735/what-is-the-best-way-to-maintain-alignment-of-a-set-of-equations-while-putting-t#comment881105_357736) mentioned, `\shortintertext` might be nicer here, if you're willing to go for the `mathtools` package.
In this case you obtain a slightly more dense result:

[image: align with \shortintertext]

Comment: There's also `\shortintertext` from `mathtools`, which would look nicer here, in my opinion.

Comment: Cannot tell the difference between short and regular intertext...lol..